# How to correctly handle cancelled tasks in Python's `asyncio.gather`

Tags: python, python-asyncio

So I'm taking another stab at the `asyncio` module now that 3.8 is out. However, I am getting unexpected results when trying to do a graceful shutdown of the event loop. Specifically I am listening for a `SIGINT`, cancelling the running `Task`s, gathering those `Task`s, and then `.stop()`ing the event loop. I know that `Task`s raise a `CancelledError` when they are cancelled which will propagate up and end my call to `asyncio.gather` unless, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently), I pass `return_exceptions=True` to `asyncio.gather`, which should cause `gather` to wait for all the `Task`s to cancel and return an array of `CancelledError`s. However, it appears that `return_exceptions=True` still results in an immediate interruption of my `gather` call if I try to `gather` cancelled `Task`s.

Here is the code to reproduce the effect. I am running python 3.8.0:

```py
# demo.py

import asyncio
import random
import signal


async def worker():
    sleep_time = random.random() * 3
    await asyncio.sleep(sleep_time)
    print(f"Slept for {sleep_time} seconds")

async def dispatcher(queue):
    while True:
        await queue.get()
        asyncio.create_task(worker())
        tasks = asyncio.all_tasks()
        print(f"Running Tasks: {len(tasks)}")

async def shutdown(loop):
    tasks = [t for t in asyncio.all_tasks() if t is not asyncio.current_task()]
    for task in tasks:
        task.cancel()
    print(f"Cancelling {len(tasks)} outstanding tasks")
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
    print(f"results: {results}")
    loop.stop()

async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: asyncio.create_task(shutdown(loop)))
    queue = asyncio.Queue()
    asyncio.create_task(dispatcher(queue))

    while True:
        await queue.put('tick')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```sh
>> python demo.py 
Running Tasks: 3
Slept for 0.3071352174511871 seconds
Running Tasks: 3
Running Tasks: 4
Slept for 0.4152310498820644 seconds
Running Tasks: 4
^CCancelling 4 outstanding tasks
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 38, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "/Users/max.taggart/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/Users/max.taggart/.pyenv/versions/3.8.0/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 608, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError
```

I'm guessing there is still something about the event loop that I don't understand, but I would expect all the `CancelledError`s to come back as an array of objects stored in `results` and then be able to continue on rather than to see an error immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### What causes the error?

Problem with using `asyncio.all_tasks()` is that it returns ALL tasks even those you didn't create directly. Change your code following way to see what you cancel:

```
for task in tasks:
    print(task)
    task.cancel()
```

You'll see not only `worker` related tasks, but also:

```
<Task pending coro=<main() running at ...>
```

Cancelling `main` leads to mess inside `asyncio.run(main())` and you get error. Let's do fast/dirty modification to exclude this task from cancellation:

```
tasks = [
    t 
    for t 
    in asyncio.all_tasks() 
    if (
        t is not asyncio.current_task()
        and t._coro.__name__ != 'main'
    )
]

for task in tasks:
    print(task)
    task.cancel()
```

Now you'll see your `results`.

### loop.stop() leads to error

While you achieved `results`, you will get another error `Event loop stopped before Future completed`. It happens because `asyncio.run(main())` want to run until `main()` finished.

You have to restructure your code to allow coroutine you passed into `asyncio.run` be done instead of stopping event loop or, for example, use [loop.run_forever()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_forever) instead of `asyncio.run`.

Here's fast/dirty demonstration of what I mean:

```
async def shutdown(loop):
    # ...

    global _stopping
    _stopping = True
    # loop.stop()

_stopping = False

async def main():
    # ...

    while not _stopping:
        await queue.put('tick')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Now your code will work without errors. Don't use code above on practice, it's just an example. Try to restructure your code as I mentioned above.

### How to correctly handle tasks

**Don't use `asyncio.all_tasks()`.**

If you create some task you want to cancel in the future, store it and cancel only stored tasks. Pseudo code:

```
i_created = []

# ...

task = asyncio.create_task(worker())
i_created.append(task)

# ...

for task in i_created:
    task.cancel()
```

It may not seem convenient, but it's a way to make sure you don't cancel something you don't want to be cancelled.

### One more thing

Note also that that `asyncio.run()` does [much more](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3a0a6bbccfcd9d18afe5575617aefaee9fa37a5/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L8) than just starting event loop. In particular, [it cancels](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f3a0a6bbccfcd9d18afe5575617aefaee9fa37a5/Lib/asyncio/runners.py#L46) all hanging tasks before finishing. It may be useful in some cases, although I advise to handle all cancellations manually instead.